# Creating a summary of contents on civil mailings

Tags: mailing

Wondering if there is a feature in a civi mailing to create a summary of the various stories that are being included in a mailing whereby each story title in the summary is clickable and takes you further down in the email to the corresponding story.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an automatic feature but this is what html anchor tags do. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_another_section_on_the_same_page

So at the top of your html mail you can put

`<a href="#thing1">Thing 1</a>`

and repeat for each title/summary, and then use the id in your stories lower down like

`<div id="thing1">Here is the actual story.</div>`